# scalaz, read and map the lines of a file

Tags: scala, scalaz

The following code to read and map the lines of a file works ok:

```
def readLines(fileName: String) = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines
def toInt(line: String) = line.toInt

val numbers: Iterator[Int] = readLines("/tmp/file.txt").map(toInt).map(_ * 2)
println(numbers.toList)
```

I get an iterator of `Int`s if the executing goes well. But the program throws an exception if the file is not found, or some line contains letters.

How can I transform the program to use scalaz monads and get a `Disjunction[Exception, List[Int]]`?

I tried this on [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) 7.2.6, but it does not compile:

```
  import scalaz.Scalaz._
  import scalaz._

  def readLines(fileName: String): Disjunction[Any, List[String]] =
    try { scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList.right }
    catch { case e: java.io.IOException => e.left}

  def toInt(line: String): Disjunction[Any, Int] =
    try { line.toInt.right }
    catch { case e: NumberFormatException => e.left}

  val numbers: Disjunction[Any, Int] = for {
    lines: List[String] <- readLines("/tmp/file.txt")
    line: String <- lines
    n: Int <- toInt(line)
  } yield (n * 2)
```

it fails to compile with these errors:

```
Error:(89, 37) could not find implicit value for parameter M: scalaz.Monoid[Any]
    lines: List[String] <- readLines("/tmp/file.txt")
Error:(89, 37) not enough arguments for method filter: (implicit M: scalaz.Monoid[Any])scalaz.\/[Any,List[String]].
Unspecified value parameter M.
    lines: List[String] <- readLines("/tmp/file.txt")
Error:(91, 20) could not find implicit value for parameter M: scalaz.Monoid[Any]
    n: Int <- toInt(line)
Error:(91, 20) not enough arguments for method filter: (implicit M: scalaz.Monoid[Any])scalaz.\/[Any,Int].
Unspecified value parameter M.
    n: Int <- toInt(line)
```

I don't understand the errors. what is the problem?

and how to improve this code, so that it does not read all the file into memory, but it reads and maps each line at a time?

---

**Update: Answer from Filippo**

```
  import scalaz._

  def readLines(fileName: String) = \/.fromTryCatchThrowable[List[String], Exception] {
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList
  }

  def toInt(line: String) = \/.fromTryCatchThrowable[Int, NumberFormatException](line.toInt)

  type λ[+A] = Exception \/ A

  val numbers = for {
    line: String <- ListT[λ, String](readLines("/tmp/file.txt"))
    n: Int       <- ListT[λ, Int](toInt(line).map(List(_)))
  } yield n * 2

  println(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question, I would simply use the `Iterator` out of the `fromFile` method:

```
val lines: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines
```

If you want to use `toInt` to convert `String` to `Int`:

```
import scala.util.Try

def toInt(line: String): Iterator[Int] =
  Try(line.toInt).map(Iterator(_)).getOrElse(Iterator.empty)
```

Then `numbers` could look like:

```
val numbers = readLines("/tmp/file.txt").flatMap(toInt).map(_ * 2)
```

**EDIT**

Due the presence of all these `try` and `catch`, if you want to keep using that `monadic-for` I would suggest to check a `scalaz` helper like `.fromTryCatchThrowable` on `Disjunction`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def readLines(fileName: String): Disjunction[Exception, List[String]] =
  Disjunction.fromTryCatchThrowable(scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList)

def toInt(line: String): Disjunction[Exception, Int] =
  Disjunction.fromTryCatchThrowable(line.toInt)
```

Now we also have `Exception` instead of `Any` as the left type.

```
val numbers = for {
  lines: List[String] <- readLines("/tmp/file.txt")
  line: String        <- lines                      // The problem is here
  n: Int              <- toInt(line)
} yield n * 2
```

The problem with this `monadic-for` is that the first and third line are using the `Disjunction` context but the second one uses the `List` monad. Using a monad transformer like `ListT` or `DisjunctionT` here is possible but probably overkill.

**EDIT - to reply the comment**

As mentioned, if we want a single `monadic-for` comprehension, we need a monad transformer, in this case `ListT`. The `Disjunction` has two type parameters while a Monad `M[_]` obviously only one. We need to handle this "extra type parameter", for instance using `type lambda`:

```
def readLines(fileName: String) = \/.fromTryCatchThrowable[List[String], Exception] {
  fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList
}

val listTLines = ListT[({type λ[+a] = Exception \/ a})#λ, String](readLines("/tmp/file.txt"))
```

What is the type of `listTLines`? The `ListT` transformer: `ListT[\/[Exception, +?], String]`

The last step in the original `for-comprehension` was `toInt`:

```
def toInt(line: String) = \/.fromTryCatchThrowable[Int, NumberFormatException](line.toInt)

val listTNumber = ListT[\/[Exception, +?], Int](toInt("line"))
```

What is the type of `listTNumber`? It doesn't even compile, because the toInt return an `Int` and not a `List[Int]`. We need a `ListT` to join that `for-comprehension`, one trick could be changing `listTNumber` to:

```
val listTNumber = ListT[\/[Exception, +?], Int](toInt("line").map(List(_)))
```

Now we have both steps:

```
val numbers = for {
  line: String <- ListT[\/[Exception, +?], String](readLines("/tmp/file.txt"))
  n: Int       <- ListT[\/[Exception, +?], Int](toInt(line).map(List(_)))
} yield n * 2

scala> numbers.run.getOrElse(List.empty) foreach println
2
20
200
```

If you are wondering why all this unwrapping:

```
scala> val unwrap1 = numbers.run
unwrap1: scalaz.\/[Exception,List[Int]] = \/-(List(2, 20, 200))

scala> val unwrap2 = unwrap1.getOrElse(List())
unwrap2: List[Int] = List(2, 20, 200)

scala> unwrap2 foreach println
2
20
200
```

*(assuming that the sample file contains the lines: 1, 10, 100)*

**EDIT - comment about compilation issues**

The code above compiles thanks to the Kind Projector plugin:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" % "kind-projector_2.11" % "0.5.2")
```

With [Kind Projector](https://index.scala-lang.org/non/kind-projector/kind-projector) we can have anonymous types like:

```
Either[Int, +?]          // equivalent to: type R[+A] = Either[Int, A]
```

Instead of:

```
type IntOrA[A] = Either[Int, A]

// or
({type L[A] = Either[Int, A]})#L
```

Comment: cool for the `Disjunction.fromTryCatchThrowable`. Ok, I see the problem  (from lines to line), but what is a solution? I've updated the question to make the objective more clear.

Comment: wow, it works! (the program was not compiling, but it was quickly fixed. I've added your answer (fixed) to the bottom of my question. I'll remove it from my question if you can fix it in your answer).

Comment: Is there some explanation or documentation about ListT? I didn't find anything about in on http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/index.html

Comment: I haven't found much documentation in the past about `ListT`. I would suggest to check some presentations about Monad Transformer in general to solve the `F[G[X]]` combination problem, like https://speakerdeck.com/gabro/monad-transformers-just-why . For `ListT` specific information I would go straight to the test code: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/ListTTest.scala

Answer (score 0):

First, the compiler alerts that you´re using for comprehensions mixing types. Your code is transformed by the compiler as that :

```
readLines("/tmp/file.txt") flatMap { lines => lines } map { line => toInt(line) }
```

The definition of flatMap is:

```
def flatMap[A,B](ma: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]
```

In your case F is the \/, and this **flatMap { lines => lines }** is wrong. The compiler alerts with a message like this "*List[Nothing] required: scalaz.\/[Any,Int]*" because treats list as one function with no parameters and List[Nothing] as result type. Change your code like that:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._
import scalaz._

def readLines(fileName: String): Disjunction[Any, List[String]] =
 try { scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList.right }
  catch { case e: java.io.IOException => e.left}

def toInt(line: List[String]): Disjunction[Any, List[Int]] =
  try { (line map { _ toInt }).right }
  catch { case e: NumberFormatException => e.left}                                                

val numbers = for {
  lines <- readLines("/tmp/file.txt")
  n <- toInt(lines)
 } yield (n map (_ * 2))
```

That works.

For read line by line maybe FileInputStream can be easier:

```
 fis = new FileInputStream("/tmp/file.txt");
 reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
 String line = reader.readLine();

 while(line != null){
   System.out.println(line);
   line = reader.readLine();
 }
```

Or you can test the readline function from Source class.

Comment: `def toInt(lines: List[String]): Disjunction[Any, Int]` does not make sense, as it should return `Disjunction[Any, List[Int]]`. but then, the `yield (n*2)` would need to be transformed to `yield (n.map(_ * 2))`, which makes things unreadable. I've updated the question to make the objective more clear.

Comment: I´ve just change the code. Check it out if that if what you´re expecting